# Cache Records Being Stored for Invalid Paths

Tags: cache

I'm trying to figure out why I have so many template cache records and when I look in my database `templatecaches` table I'm seeing a bunch of rows being stored for paths that don't exist. For example there are a bunch of Wordpress-like paths that presumably a bot tried to hit:

```
site:wp-admin
site:wp-content/themes/konzept/includes/uploadify/uploads/cache.php
```

Also a bunch of records with file extensions like `.zip` and `.rar`:

```
site:website.tar.gz
site:website.rar
site:webroot.zip
```

All of these paths should have thrown a 404 when the bogus URL was hit, and therefore should not have triggered a cache record to be created. Why am I getting all these junk cache records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a `{% cache %}` tag around my global `header` template, which is pulled in by every template, including the 404 template. Apparently Craft doesn't care if the 404 template is being called or not, if it sees a `{% cache %}` tag it's caching that content.

The Wordpress and file extension paths are all from bots pinging the site trying to find a vulnerability, and every time those URLs threw a 404 a new cache record was created for the header.

So I set a variable in my 404 template and checked if it was set in my header template before caching:

**404.html**

```
{% extends 'layouts/_global' %}

{% set fourohfour = true %}

{% block pageBody %}
    <h1>404, yo.</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

**header.html** (included in `layouts/_global`)

```
{% cache if fourohfour is not defined %}
    <nav>
        {% for page in craft.entries.section('Pages').level(1).all %}
            <a href="{{ page.url }}"{% if craft.app.request.segment(1) == page.slug %} class="current"{% endif %}>{{ page.title }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </nav>
{% endcache %}
```